# Meteor DB Inconsitent outside of template

Tags: meteor

There is a good deal of code so people can see exactly what I mean.  I am working on a meteor app and I encountered some very strange behavior from the Mongo DB database so I wrote this simple test program to find out what was going on.  The behavior I observed was that when you reference a Meteor/Mongo DB collection outside of a template and inside you get different results.  If you call functions to insert into a collection outside of a template the DB rows are only find able until the page reloads.  When the rows are inserted from a calling originating from inside a template they persist but are not referable by the look up code outside the template.  To replicate this you can load the program below.  On page load it will alert you 1.  If you click insert 3 times and click count you will see 4.  If you reload you will get an alert of 1 then if you click count it will say 5.  If this is a known and designed behavior are there any tricks to get around it or do you really have to use templates for everything when using meteor?

test.HTML

```
 <head>
    <title>Templates</title>
</head>

<body>
{{> hello}}
</body>


<template name="hello">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    {{greeting}}
    <input type="button" value="Insert" class="insert"/>
    <input type="button" value="Count" class="count"/>
    <input type="button" value="Remove All" class="remove"/>
</template>
```

And with it test.js

```
    Test = new Meteor.Collection("test");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.hello.greeting = function () {
        return "Welcome to test";
    };

    Template.hello.events({
        'click input.insert': function () {
            // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
            Test.insert({testid:"test"});
        },
        'click input.count': function () {
            alert(Test.find().count());
        },
        'click input.remove': function () {
            var cursor = Test.find();
            cursor.fetch().forEach(function(test){
                Test.remove(test._id);
            });
        }
    });
    Test.insert({test:"test"});
    var testCursor = Test.find();
    alert(testCursor.count());
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not alone - this is by far the most misunderstood aspect of how meteor works. I address some of the answer in my post on [guards](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards), but here's the quick summary:

- Your data isn't ready the instant the client starts running. It takes time to transmit from the server to the client.
- Your template will render immediately and not wait for the data (unless you use something like iron-router with a `waitOn` callback).
- Meteor is built with these assumptions in mind (render the template - when documents change then update the UI).

In your case, you will always see "1" initially because you always do an insert as soon as the client starts. Sometime later, the client will be updated with all of the documents.

To answer your last question - yes you should use templates. Otherwise you are working against the way the platform was implemented.

Comment: So is there in effect both a local and server side DB? Does Find not actually wait for a response from the server before returning you the results?

Comment: Yes and yes. The local DB is called minimongo. It's a small synchronous version of mongo which runs on the client. All finds on the client hit minimongo and do not wait for the server. In the background, documents are synced to and from the server. The trick is that meteor understands that collection cursors are reacive - meaning that after documents are synced, the UI should respond. This is a big concept to cover in a comment. :)